# Sqoop export geometry column : ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type 1111 (postgresql geometry point 3945)

Tags: postgresql, geometry, postgis, sqoop, cloudera-cdp

Using Sqoop export on CDP cluster (hdfs), I'm trying to export data geometry to Postgresql table but I'm facing a Sqoop ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type 1111 for column 'geom'.

The 'geom' column definition on PostGis is : geometry (Point,3945).

Here is my Sqoop export query :

```
sqoop export --connect "jdbc:postgresql://$database_server/$database_source_name" \
--username $username --password $password_alias \
--table $database_table_name \
--export-dir "${DIR_OUT_HDFS}" \
--fields-terminated-by '|' --lines-terminated-by "\n" \
-- --schema $database_table_name  1>>${LOG_FILE} 2>>${LOG_FILE}
```

Here is Sqoop output error :

```
ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type 1111 for column geom
ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.parseColumn(ClassWriter.java:1417)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.myGenerateParser(ClassWriter.java:1555)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generateParser(ClassWriter.java:1518)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generateClassForColumns(ClassWriter.java:1979)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1764)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:106)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:77)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:113)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:81)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:187)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:241)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:250)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:259)
```

Here my last Sqoop export query where I added --map-column-java geom=String but still having issue (output msg = failed to execute):

```
sqoop export --connect "jdbc:postgresql://$database_server/$database_source_name" \
--username $username --password $password_alias \
--table $database_table_name \
--export-dir "${DIR_OUT_HDFS}" \
--fields-terminated-by '|' \
--lines-terminated-by "\n" \
--input-null-string '\\N' \
--input-null-non-string '\\N' \
--map-column-java geom=String \
-- --schema $schema_destination 1>>${LOG_FILE} 2>>${LOG_FILE}
```